# LLVM branch instruction: if statement or loop in the source?

Tags: assembly, llvm, compiler-optimization, llvm-ir

For a conditional branch instruction in LLVM IR (as a terminator of a basic block), I would like to determine whether it corresponds to a loop or an if statement in the *source code*. Is there a way to analyze this?

Comment: There isn't necessarily a concept of source code when dealing with LLVM IR. Are you talking about e.g. IR generated by clang from C or C++ code?

Comment: Yes! That's what I meant (IR generated by clang from C).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually, a branch forward is an "if statement" and a branch backward is a loop. However this might be hidden behind some complexity, e.g. the frontend might create a conditional branch forward which leads to an unconditional branch backward, so overall a loop.

If you want to be sure, generate the IR with debug information, and then use that information - particularly, the line number - to understand what the original code was.